# Dynamics 365 Unified Interface editable subgrid not showing error message coming from Canceled step of any workflow

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-uci

We have a workflow being called through an editable subgrid. We are sending a message when the workflow gets canceled. This is working perfectly in classic interface but not in Unified interface. Everything is working except the grid is not receiving any message when workflow is cancelled. We would like to know the solution to this problem.

Comment: Can we see the screenshot of behavior you expect & where is it missing today?

Comment: I am sorry @ArunVinoth, we can not provide a screenshot right now. Please let me know if my question if confusing and I will try to simplify it.